# NextJS serverless page has dependencies even though it shouldn't

Tags: webpack, next.js, serverless

NextJS claims that with `serverless` target in `next.config.js`...

```
module.exports = {
    target: "serverless"
}
```

... [each page in the `pages` directory is output as a standalone lambda with 0 dependencies](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-8#serverless-nextjs).

However, with a simple NextJS project containing a file `/pages/Home.js`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {

    const user = "user";
    return {props: {user}}
}

export default function Home({user}) {

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{user}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

... I end up with a file `.next/serverless/pages/Home.js` that still has dependencies in `.next/serverless/chunks` directory and that can't be used as a standalone function with a signature like a NodeJS http server callback.

Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?